# PSU is not the problem, is it the motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I think my motherboard is broken. First I thought the PSU was broken, but after I replaced the PSU, I only see that the cpu fan makes a little movement and then nothing happens. I also checked if the on/off button cables are in the right place.

Also the fan of the powersupply isn't working, I tried two different PSU's and bothe are new, so the change of 2 doa's is minimal.

Do you think my motherboard is dead?

Comment: no!  no, wait.  yes!  send it to me and i'll fix it.

Comment: That wont be an option, can you tell me what you have in mind?

Comment: What are the make & model of the power supply and motherboard?

Comment: ms tech powersupply 520 watt, medion computer type: pc mt8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely could be. When I encounter this I usually also check the RAM and the CPU. If you can get your hands on some spares, it is worth a shot.

Have you unplugged everything else from the motherboard except the CPU and RAM?

Comment: yes, only the two powercables were plugged

Comment: btw, the PSU won't turn on unless the motherboard completes the circuit. The reasons could be a bad MB, bad CPU, or in some cases I have seen, bad RAM.

Comment: when there is no RAM installed the mainboard will give a beep mostly.

Comment: Did you look for any burst capacitors / blackened areas?

Comment: "Definitely could be" ... good one :)

Comment: no burst capacitors

Comment: Molly... yes, that is a bit awkward.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to make sure the Clear CMOS jumper is set to the correct pins, and make sure you don't have any shorts in the system (e.g., make sure there are no loose screws, and make sure you don't have any stray motherboard standoffs touching the back of the board where there aren't any screw holes).

Also, some motherboards require you to plug in multiple power connectors, not just the 20- or 24-pin main power connector.

> Also the fan of the powersupply isn't working, I tried two different PSU's and bothe are new, so the change of 2 doa's is minimal.

Some power supplies require you to plug the **power supply's** fan into the motherboard.  Double-check whether your power supply powers its own fan, or if it requires you to plug a 3- or 4-prong connector into one of the fan headers on the motherboard.  You can perform a simple power supply test by using a paper clip to short the green wire with one of the black wires in the main (20- or 24-pin) power connector.  If the fan runs, something is goofy with your motherboard.  If the fan doesn't run, you should use a voltmeter or multimeter to confirm that the power supply is, indeed, producing the correct voltages on the power connectors.

Comment: it's a 4 prong connector which is plugged in. the cpu fan does move a little, but doesn't work when I connect the power cable to the psu

Comment: Dumb question, but the switch on the back (if there is one) is set to 115V instead of 230V, right?  Also, does the CPU fan spin freely when you give it a soft spin with your finger?