# computer lights up but then nothing

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, crash

my computer was working fine today morning. then when i switchced it on in the evening nothing..the led near the lights up but thats its not beep sound or anything. even the fans on the PSU and motherboard don't turn on.

intially with i switch on the power the mouse would glow and there would be beep sound but now tht beep sound is missing though the mouse glows.

how to fix it? anyone

Comment: can you specify the Mac model like `MacBook early 2006` for example

Comment: its intel pentium dual core

Comment: Sounds like the PSU died.

Comment: check these questions [here](http://superuser.com/q/91740/443279) &  [here](http://superuser.com/a/208577/443279) as they have answers marked as coccect

Comment: but then how come the led of power button or the Mouse glows ?

Comment: The PSU provides more than one voltage, all of them are required.

Comment: You should include your system specs.